# Boot failure in virtual box vm

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I have created a vm in virtual box using 'vmdk' file. the vm creation is successful but when i tried to power on the vm i am getting the following error "FATAL:  INT18:  BOOT FAILURE". I tried to convert the vmdk to VHD file and tried to create the vm but getting the same error. Could please someone help in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Enable `EFI`:

Settings `->` System `->` Motherboard

OR

> vboxmanage modifyvm *vmname* --firmware efi

Answer (score 0):

You didn't gave us too many details, but, have you made more than 1 partition? If yes, try to set the active partition. If not, what guest OS are you trying to virtualize whit what host?

Comment: I did not try partition.. the guest OS and and the host are Linux OS only.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to Hard disk is checked in (Boot order)
[image]